# How can I implement Jitsi Web in my Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet

Does anyone work Jitsi framework on the web using the Flutter project?

trying to implement it flutter web but can not find exactly solution. In flutter mobile app it is work perfactly but in web can not work or i can not run it have anyone provide specific solution